# Observing Java Null pointer exception issue when we try to fetch the records from Informix db

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, informix

**Issue:**
In DB, Have around 20000 records and I'm trying to generate the report of all the records via UI ,it fetches the records available in db till 12679th record . When it tries to generate the records for 12680th one, Observing the below mentioned error in the UI page. As a result, observing java null pointer exception issue.

Note: Handled the code to fetch around 30000 records via preparedStatement object(setMaxRows)

**Errors Observed:**

Unable to Execute Query:**Could not open database table**(root.tablename).

select  * from tablename a where x=12680 order by y;

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

And it has been observed due to this piece of code
s1 is the select query which we are parsing as an argument to the prepareStatement.
pStmt is nothing but the preparedStatement object.
dbCon is connection object
Looped through the query for each records one by one

```
  private Connection dbCon;
  PreparedStatement pStmt = null;    

   try {
              pStmt = dbCon.prepareStatement (s1);
              try {
                         pStmt.setMaxRows(30000);
                         rs = pStmt.executeQuery ();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println ("\nUnable to Execute Query:" + e.getMessage() +"Stack Trace::"+e.getStackTrace() + " (Query: " + s1 + ")\n");
              }
  } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println ("\nUnable to Prepare Query:" + e.getMessage() + " (Query: " + s1 + ")\n");
    }
```

When we execute the select query command for 12680th record via CLI informix db access, the query seems to be working fine and it fetches the record without any issues.

It looks like a java issue because if its a db issue ,it should not allow us to fetch the query results via CLI but it allows us to fetch without any issues via  informix db access.

Got struct at this point on how to solve this java exception issue?

Could someone guide me to proceed further on this activity to fix the issue?

**Expectation:**
Need to capture all the 20000 records

Comment: Are you sure that there are no null values at that point in the table?

Comment: Post the entire exception stack trace as that is very useful in determining cause.

Comment: If there are null values ,it should not fetch the values via CLI right. But it fetches the record without any issues via CLI dbaccess

Comment: @Andy :Unable to Execute Query:Could not open database table (root.tablename).Stack Trace::[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@f7f540 (Query:  select  * from  tablename  where x=12680 order by y)

Comment: I would check if it is a problem with the data in one of the column. Is it ok when you `select column1, column2, ... columnN from tablename where x=12680` instead of `select *`? If not, then try to find if you can `select column1 from tablename where x=12680` then `select column2 from tablename where x=12680` etc. etc.

Comment: Can you show us your Informix and JDBC driver version?

Comment: @MichałNiklas : Tried with  select column1,column2 ...columnN from tablename where x =12680 -> still facing the same issue

Comment: @MichalNiklas - Informix server version 11.50.FC5

Comment: What if you select just one column? Test it with 1st and 2nd column. What version of JDBC driver do you use? Can you select this row using ODBC or other technology?

Comment: You mentioned you are using a prepared statement, I guess you are not using that from dbacces (you could if you write an SPL to do the fetch)  so both 'runs' (dbaccess/jdbc) would differ.
The text "Could not open database table" correspond to error -242. That looks like an error coming from the server (not originated on the client).  The ISAM error should give you more clues about why, but you need to catch the exception and show the errors numbers.
Maybe trapping the error with "onmode -I 242" can give you more info (server side). (onmode -I to disable it) will generate an AF.

Comment: Does that table has any indexes? Try the forcing going through the index or with a full scan to see if it makes any difference.  Something like "select {+FULL(t1)} count(c1) from t1 where c1=123" or "select {+AVOID_FULL(t1)} count(c1) from t1 where c1=123" but with your table.

Comment: @MichałNiklas:                                                                                                               # java -version
java version "1.5.0_51"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_51-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_51-b10, mixed mode)

bash-3.2# java com.informix.jdbc.Version
IBM Informix JDBC Driver Version 3.00.JC2

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC5

Comment: It is a very old environment. Can you try it with the newest Informix JDBC driver available on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/jdbc and with new Java?